# Adding swift framework to Workspace - Use of unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-frameworks, xcode-workspace

I am trying to add a custom framework to my workspace and I can't get my main project to compile. Both projects are top level in the Workspace, and I have added the framework to the Embedded Binaries.

[image]

When I build my main project, none of the calls to the framework can be found. 
The framework builds without errors.

What step am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that my .swift files were in folder references. Apparently you can't have folder references in a framework. Moving them directly into Groups solved my problem immediately.